# How to put var with text type value into a jQuery Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a function to get some json array data from php file (`getdata.php`). This function require a string data type variable from select option element that in the next step will be used in `getdata.php`.

I use `var text = $('#element option:selected').text();` to create my variable. I'm sure this var text contain the right text value (I tried to show it using alert and it showed up). But, when i pass it into my function, this text value seems like dont match the data type that should be used. I don't know the structure of doing it. In `getdata.php`, i use this var to complete a mysql query. I use `$_GET` to fetch that variable. I tried it with `var number=$('#element option:selected').val();` and it worked, but `.text()` it didn't run well.

I'll really appreciate any advice to solve this problem. Thank you.

Below is my script function code.

```
    $("#element1").change(function(){
        var text = $('#element option:selected').text();
        getAjaxData(text);
    });

    function getAjaxData(text){
        $.getJSON("getdata.php",{text:text} ,function(json){
        //some operations here
    }
```

Comment: sorry, it's a typo. i've edited it.

Comment: can you add your 'element'  in question. is it text box or else ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use `.val( )` if it's a textarea or input field.

From the jQuery Documentation:

> The .text() method cannot be used on form inputs or scripts. To set or get the text value of input or textarea elements, use the .val() method. To get the value of a script element, use the .html() method.

Comment: btw, how if i want to convert the .text() into a variable that acceptable and can be used in my function? is there any trick to do that?

Comment: @anjaryes what exactly do you mean? can you give me more information?

Comment: is it possible to convert var text generated from .text() into another kind of variable that can be used in my script function? because in my query i use that text to choose a column.

Comment: @anjaryes it would be best if you were to create a new question specifically for that and give us exactly the code that you want to use. You can give us the link here.

Answer (score 1):

`$(#element).text()` will not return value from input or select .

to get value from input, select you need to use `.val()` function .

`$(#element).val()` will give value of selected element in select box

to get text of selected option you need to use below code

```
 var text = $("#element option:selected").text();
```

to get value of selected option you need to use below code

```
 var value = $("#element option:selected").val();
```

or

```
 var value = $("#element").val();
```

Comment: how if i want to convert the .text() into a variable that acceptable and can be used in my function ? is there any trick to do that?

Comment: Your text and value are same??

Comment: @anjaryes  if your text is in numbers and you want to convert you text in integer value integer  then use parseInt($("#element option:selected").text());

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#element1").change(function(){
  var text = $('#element').val();
  getAjaxData(text);
});

function getAjaxData(text){
  $.getJSON("getdata.php",{text:text} ,function(json){
  //some operations here
}
```